# Swapping objects in tuples - python

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability

I have tuples in the form of:

```
a[i][j][k]
```

k ∈ [0,1]
a is made up of objects T, that are included in a list teams.

What I want, is to swap the position of all pairs a[i][j][0] and a[i][j][1]. so:

```
a[i][j][0], a[i][j][1] = a[i][j][1], a[i][j][0]
```

As a is a tuple, I understand it is immutable, which is the reason that this does not work:

```
for i in range(0, len(teams)-1):
    for j in range(0, len(teams)/2):
        a[i][j][0],a[i][j][1] = a[i][j][1],a[i][j][0]
```

I have tried converting a to a list (L = list(a)), but without success.

Can somebody help me with suggestions? Sorry in case my nomenclatur is not perfect yet, this is my first question on SO :)

Thanks

Comment: We would need to see a [mcve]. is `a` tuple of tuple of tuples?

Comment: Where does `teams` come from?

Comment: Is the outer most layer a tuple or a list?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.The answer from @Jean-FrançoisFabre below has helped me solve the issue. My matrix is a list of a list of a tuple. I was able to transfer it to a list of a list of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's say `a` is a `tuple` of `tuple`s of `tuple`s.

I would

- convert it to a list of lists of lists
- do whatever I want
- convert it back to the original format if needed

example:

```
a = (((1,2),(3,4)),((10,20),(30,40)))

a_as_list = [[list(x) for x in b] for b in a]

print(a_as_list)

# now manipulate elements:

a_as_list[0][0] = [a_as_list[0][0][1],a_as_list[0][0][0]]

a_as_tuple = tuple(tuple(tuple(x) for x in b) for b in a_as_list)


print(a_as_tuple)
```

result:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[10, 20], [30, 40]]]
(((2, 1), (3, 4)), ((10, 20), (30, 40)))
```

as you see, the tuples were converted to list, worked on, then converted back to tuples

EDIT: if `a` is a list of list of tuples you cannot do:

```
a[i][j][0], a[i][j][1] = a[i][j][1], a[i][j][0]
```

but you can recreate the inner tuple:

```
a[i][j] = a[i][j][1],a[i][j][0]
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a quick fix with the existing quote I has.

Comment: @MaximilianA.Graves see my edit, that should be enough

Comment: Perfect. I guess I have to read and learn a lot more about the difference between lists and tuples. But this was already very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

We can simply do this using Python's [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

```
a[j][k] = tuple(reversed(a[j][k]))
```

Comment: I'll try this also. This really seems a lot more economical.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Tuples are immutables indeed. `a` might be a list, or even a list of lists. So this code:

```
L = list(a)
```

won't change anything. The problem appears to be that `a` is a list of lists of tuples. `a[i][j]` is a tuple, and it's not possible to assign new values to it:

```
>>> t = ('a', 'b')
>>> t[0] = 'b'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

## Possible solution

If you're working with 3-D matrices, [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) could probably help you. It supports [advanced indexing and slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> table = np.arange(18).reshape(3,3,2)
>>> table
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])
>>> table[:, :, [0, 1]] = table[:, :, [1, 0]]
>>> table
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 3,  2],
        [ 5,  4]],

       [[ 7,  6],
        [ 9,  8],
        [11, 10]],

       [[13, 12],
        [15, 14],
        [17, 16]]])
```

Elements inside the matrix don't have to be numbers, they could be any objects:

```
>>> class T(str):
...   pass
... 
>>> T('test')
'test'
>>> m = np.array([[(T(1), T(2))],[(T(3), T(4))]])
>>> m[:, :, [0, 1]] = m[:, :, [1, 0]]
>>> m
array([[['2', '1']],

       [['4', '3']]], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will play around with numpy also!